# Nigeria to India via Istanbul

Tags: turkey

I will be traveling to India from Nigeria via istanbul. I have 14 hours to spent at airport. can I get any visa at istanbul airport to explore the city ? I don’t have USA or Schengen visa

Comment: What's your passport?

Comment: This is the Ministry of Foreign Affairs' web page about visa procedures. [Here.](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa )

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no visas to be issued at the airport<sup>*</sup>. All visas are now issued online ("e-visa") or from the consulate / embassy.

If you are an Indian passport holder, you do not meet the requirements for the e-visa and will have to apply in advance if you want to visit Turkey during your layover:

> India: Diplomatic passport holders are exempt from visa for their
>   travels to Turkey up to 90 days. Ordinary, Special and Service
>   passport holders are required to have visa to enter Turkey. Ordinary,
>   Special and Service passport holders with a valid Schengen members or
>   USA, UK, Ireland visa or residence permit may get their single entry
>   e-Visas valid for one month via the website www.evisa.gov.tr, provided
>   that they meet certain conditions.

If you are a Nigerian citizen, the same rules apply:

> Nigeria: Ordinary, official/service passport holders are required to
>   have visa to enter Turkey. These passport holders with a valid
>   Schengen members or USA, UK, Ireland visa or residence permit may get
>   their single entry e-Visas valid for one month e-Visas via the website
>   www.evisa.gov.tr, provided that they meet certain conditions.

Source: [Ministry of Foreign Affairs Turkey](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa).

*<sup>*</sup>You could arrive at the airport and use one of the kiosks to get an e-visa, but you would still have to meet the e-visa requirements.*